# Direct proof that a function is strictly monotonic

Tags: functions, proof-writing, monotone-functions

Given is the function $f : \mathbb{N} \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\dfrac{4x-2}{3x}$.

I must now prove directly that the function is strictly monotonic. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I dont even know how to start. Its my first time proving a monotonic behavior. (I know what monotony is but I dont know how to write a formal direct proof)

Comment: Try (a+b)/c = a/c+b/c

Comment: Sorry what do u mean?

Comment: @Lachkus, we mean you should write in your post what you tried to solve your problem so far, otherwise moderators will close your question very soon.

Comment: By proving if $x<y$ then $f(x) < f(y)$ always.  As the domain is strictly positive integers we can use $x \ge 1$ as a given.

Comment: What Andrew Zhang means is $\frac {4x-2}3x = \frac {4x}{3x} - \frac 2{3x}$.

Comment: Did you try to express and simplify $f(n+1)-f(n)$, for example?

Comment: THere's so many way to do it:  Is $\frac{4y-2}{3y} - \frac {4x-2}{3x}=\frac{3x(4y-2)-3y(4x-2)}{12xy}> 0$ if $y > x$? If $y=x+k$ what is $\frac{4y-2}{3y}$ and how does it compare to $\frac {4x-2}{3y}$?  $\frac {4x-2}{3x}= 1-\frac 2{3x}$ and as $x$ gets larger....?  Really, try *something*.  All you have to do is show that if $y > x$ then $f(y) > f(x)$ and... that shouldn't be hard or perplexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary $n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}.$ Then,
$$
f(n) = \frac{4n-2}{3n} = \frac{4}{3} - \frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{n}.
$$
From this, one easily sees that
$$
f(n+1) = \frac{4}{3} - \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
Since $\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1}$ for every $n \in \Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$, it follows that $f(n+1)>f(n)$ and this is enough to prove strict monocity (in this case, your function is strictly increasing).

I suggest that you do some worked based of my answer - I wasn't $100$% detailed because of that.